# force quit python during thread

Tags: python, multithreading, malware

I'm trying to create a program that spams your screen with terminal windows using threading and would like to create a failsafe button that force quits python when a certain parameter is met. I've tried "os._exit()" and that does not work. I am looking for a way to destroy all threads and force quit python as if my program runs for too long it will crash my computer.

```
def spam():
    for i in range(30):
        if i % 10 == 0: # if i is divisible by 10, it pauses for comedic timing 
            time.sleep(2)     
        os.system('open -a Terminal .') # opens terminal window
        playsound('/Users/omar/Downloads/boom.wav') # plays comical 'vine' funny meme audio 
        thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=spam) # creates a thread 
        thread.start()
        if pyautogui.failSafeCheck() == True or pynput.keyboard.Controller().type == 'Keyboard':
            os._exit() and thread.terminate()
        
spam() # function call
```

Comment: You can try setting the threads as daemon, that way they automatically terminate when your program ends (exits).

Comment: Also note that the way it's currently written, your program won't check for the failsafe during the 2 second sleeping period, but will only do so while creating threads, which I would assume isn't going to be much more than a few miliseconds.

Comment: thanks for the help Fillip. I did get rid of the 2 second sleeping period and "thread.daemon = True" does work. Thanks again :)